# Timeout error when connecting to the GridDB database

Tags: python, database, griddb

I'm trying to connect to GridDB using the Python API, but I keep getting an error message. Here's my code:

```py
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(
    host='localhost',
    port=2406,
    cluster_name='mycluster',
    username='admin',
    password='admin'
)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("mycontainer",
                               [["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                ["name", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                               griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)

con = store.get_container(conInfo)
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

```
griddb_python.GSException: [TIMEOUT] Timeout expired
```

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

I tried to look on the internet for a solution, but it seems nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection setting. Make sure you are using the correct IP address and port. Are you using fixed list? If yes the default string should be 127.0.0.1:10001. e.g.

```
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(
    notification_member='127.0.0.1:10001',
    cluster_name='mycluster',
    username='admin',
    password='admin'
)
```

Refer to this video for details:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHba9EgsO3A&list=PLZiizI6Euect9q64akYBkiqLMS78UTwjO&index=17